# Disappearing a submit button after being clicked in html form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have made a html form to take inputs from user. My sample code is given below:

```
   <form class="form-main" action="../php/additem.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="what" value="faculty" />
            <div class="form-item">
                <div class="form-left">
                    <label><big>Name:</big></label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-right">
                    <input class="txtbox" type="text" name="facname" id="fac_name" size="20" required >
                </div>
            </div>



            <div class="form-item">
                <div class="form-left">
                    <label><big>Education:</big></label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-right">
                    <input class="txtbox" type="text" name="educn" id="fac_edu" size="20" required >
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="buttons">
                <button class="greenbtn" type="submit" name="btn-upload" value="Add Now" id="add_fac" >Submit</button>
                <input class="orangebtn" type="reset" value="Clear" id="clear_fac" />
            </div>
</form>
```

I want to add a feature that, after the submit button being clicked it will be disappeared so that user can't double click on that. Is it possible? How will I do this?

Comment: Add an `onsubmit` handler to your function. Use JavaScript to set the button to "display: none"

Answer (score 1):

Two easiest ways would either be with javascript and have

```
<form class="form-main" action="../php/additem.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="hideSubmit()">

<script>
  function hideSubmit(){
    document.getElementById("buttons").style.display = "none";
  }
</script>
```

or jquery

```
<script>
  $(function(){ 
    $('.form-main').on('submit', function(){
      $('#buttons').hide();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> after the submit button being clicked it will be disappeared so that user can't double click on that.

You've literally described how to do it.

```js
document.getElementById('test-button').addEventListener('click', function () {
  this.remove()
})
```

```html
<button id="test-button">Click me!</button>
```

I suggest reading about [setting up events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Examples).